# Small eigenvalue of $\Delta$ under mean curvature flow

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Let $\Omega\subset R^2$ is a convex domain with smooth boundary. Evolving the $\Omega$ by evolving the $\partial \Omega$ according to 
$$
\partial_t X(x,t)=-H(x,t)n(x,t)
$$
$n(x,t)$ is outward normal vector ,$H(x,t)$ is mean curvature, $t\ge 0$. So, I have a metabolic domain $\Omega(t)$. Then consider the small eigenvalue 
$$
\begin{cases}
\Delta u(t)    =\lambda(t) u(t)       \\
u(t)|_{\partial \Omega(t)} =0
\end{cases}  
$$
$\Lambda(t)=\inf \lambda(t)$, then what is the sign of $\partial_t \Lambda(t)$?

Comment: What does symbol mean?

Comment: @JohnMa   It is positive or negative . In fact ,I guess it  will be not always positive or negative.  Whether I should to estimate the gradient of eigenfunction ?

Comment: You should be able to answer this easily using the domain monotonicity of Dirichlet eigenvalues.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   How to get the domain monotonicity under mean curvature flow ? If it is volume preserving mean curvature flow , what I should to do it ?

Comment: Convex domains shrink under mean curvature flow, so $s > t \implies \Omega_s \subset \Omega_t \implies \Lambda(s) \ge \Lambda(t)$. if you're normalising the flow then my comment does not apply.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   Thanks. About the volume preserving flow, do you have any idea ?  If I want to study this question, where is a good begin ?

Comment: Looks like there are a few articles by Zhao Liang that might be useful, e.g. *the first eigenvalue of Laplace operator under mean curvature flow*. In particular you will find detailed formulae for $\partial \Lambda / \partial t$ under the standard mean curvature flow, which (using the relationship between the standard and volume-preserving flows) might be of use to you.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   Thanks, I have read a little of Zhao Liang's paper, he consider the eigenvalue of $\partial \Omega$. But I want to know the eigenvalue of $\Omega$. Do you know any relevant paper.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Perhaps ask this question (for the volume preserving flow) on mathoverflow.